# How to disable FormControl in Reactive Form Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to disable this formControl:

```
this.step1 = this.fb.group({
      'name': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50)], disabled: true]...
```

I tried to add:

```
disabled: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add that to `formState` - 1st parameter of `fb.control`:

```
this.step1 = this.fb.group({
  'name': this.fb.control({value: '', disabled: true}, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50)])
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this works

```
'name': [{
  value: '',
  disabled: true
}, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50)], disabled: true]
```

But I am sure this does

```
'name': new FormControl([{
  value: '',
  disabled: true,
  validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50)], disabled: true]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

use `disabled:true` for this.

```
this.step1 = this.fb.group({
      name: [{value:'name',disabled:true}, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      lastname: [{value:'last name',disabled:true}, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50)]]
})
```